# Routing Traffic to Amazon ec2

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

We have Namebright domain name as dattus.com, we want to create a subdomain as test.dattus.com and redirect all it's traffic to amazon ec2 instance's elastic IP address.

Is this possible? How to do this?

PS: Existing website deployed on namebright should work as it is which is dattus.com.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, possible and easy.

In your DNS provider(which maybe route53 or anyone else) setup a new 'A' record that points test.dattus.com to your elastic ip address.